# Subscript out of range (Extract substrings from multiple comma separated strings macro in Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following list on Sheet1:

```
   COLUMN A    COLUMNB                                                      COLUMN C 
1  ADDRESS     Services(s) USED                                             VEHICLE(S) USED
2  Address1    Service4                                                     Vehicle1, Vehicle3, Vehicle4  
3  Address1    Service3                                                     Vehicle1, Vehicle3, Vehicle4
4  Address2    Service5                                                     Vehicle1, Vehicle2, Vehicle5
5  Address2    Service2                                                     Vehicle1, Vehicle6 
6  Address2    Service1, Service2, Service3, Service4, Service5, Service6   Vehicle2, Vehicle5, Vehicle6 
7  Address1    Service1, Service2, Service3, Service4, Service5, Service6   Vehicle2, Vehicle3
```

On Sheet2, I would like the following output in Column B when I enter "Address1" in cell B4

```
   COLUMN A    COLUMN B            


4              Address1                                                                 

12             Service1
13             Service2
14             Service3
15             Service4
16             Service5
17             Service6

50             Vehicle1
51             Vehicle2
52             Vehicle3
53             Vehicle4
54             Vehicle5
56             Vehicle6
```

**Worksheet_Change Code** ("Sheet2" module)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' call Function only if modifed cell is in Column "B"
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B4")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Call FilterAddress(Target.Value)
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

**Sub FilterAddress Code** (Regular module)

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterAddress(FilterVal As String)


Dim LastRow As Long
Dim FilterRng As Range, cell As Range
Dim Dict As Object
'Dim ID
Dim Vehicle As Variant
Dim VehicleArr As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim Service As Variant
Dim ServiceArr As Variant
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim My_Range As Range

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' find last row with data in column "A" (Adress)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set FilterRng = .Range("A1:C" & LastRow)

    .Range("A1").AutoFilter
    ' AutoFilter "Sheet1" according to value in "Sheet2" in Column B
    FilterRng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=FilterVal

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' create an array with size up to number of rows >> will resize it later
    ReDim ServiceArr(1 To LastRow)
    j = 1 ' init array counter

    For Each cell In .Range("B2:B" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        ' read values from cell to array using the Split function
        Service = Split(cell.Value, ",")

        For i = LBound(Service) To UBound(Service)
            Service(i) = Trim(Service(i)) ' remove extra spaces from string

            If Not Dict.exists(Service(i)) Then
                Dict.Add Service(i), Service(i)

                ' save Service Name to array >> will use it later for "Bubble-sort" and paste in "Sheet2"
                ServiceArr(j) = Service(i)
                j = j + 1 ' increment ServiceArr counter
            End If
        Next i

    Next cell
    ' resize array up to number of actual Service
    ReDim Preserve ServiceArr(1 To j - 1)

End With

Dim ServiceTmp As Variant
' Bubble-sort Service Array >> sorts the Service array from smallest to largest
For i = 1 To UBound(ServiceArr) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(ServiceArr)
        If ServiceArr(j) < ServiceArr(i) Then
            ServiceTmp = ServiceArr(j)
            ServiceArr(j) = ServiceArr(i)
            ServiceArr(i) = ServiceTmp
        End If
    Next j
Next i

' now the "fun" part >> paste to "Sheet2"
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("A1").Value = "ADDRESS"
    .Range("B4").Value = FilterVal
    .Range("C1").Value = "VEHICLE(S) USED"

    ' clear contents from previous run

    .Range("B12:B17").ClearContents
    .Range("B12:B" & UBound(ServiceArr) + 11) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ServiceArr)

End With

FilterRng.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' find last row with data in column "A" (Adress)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set FilterRng = .Range("A1:C" & LastRow)

    .Range("A1").AutoFilter
    ' AutoFilter "Sheet1" according to value in "Sheet2" in Column B
    FilterRng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=FilterVal

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' create an array with size up to number of rows >> will resize it later
    ReDim VehicleArr(1 To LastRow)
    y = 1 ' init array counter

    For Each cell In .Range("C2:C" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        ' read values from cell to array using the Split function
        Vehicle = Split(cell.Value, ",")

        For x = LBound(Vehicle) To UBound(Vehicle)
            Vehicle(x) = Trim(Vehicle(x)) ' remove extra spaces from string

            If Not Dict.exists(Vehicle(x)) Then
                Dict.Add Vehicle(x), Vehicle(x)

                ' save Vehicle Name to array >> will use it later for "Bubble-sort" and paste in "Sheet2"
                VehicleArr(y) = Vehicle(x)
                y = y + 1 ' increment VehicleArr counter
            End If
        Next x

    Next cell
    ' resize array up to number of actual Vehicle
    ReDim Preserve VehicleArr(1 To y - 1)

End With

Dim VehicleTmp As Variant
' Bubble-sort Vehicle Array >> sorts the Vehicle array from smallest to largest
For x = 1 To UBound(VehicleArr) - 1
    For y = x + 1 To UBound(VehicleArr)
        If VehicleArr(y) < VehicleArr(x) Then
            VehicleTmp = VehicleArr(y)
            VehicleArr(y) = VehicleArr(x)
            VehicleArr(x) = VehicleTmp
        End If
    Next y
Next x

' now the "fun" part >> paste to "Sheet2"
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("A1").Value = "ADDRESS"
    .Range("B4").Value = FilterVal
    .Range("C1").Value = "VEHICLE(S) USED"

    ' clear contents from previous run

    .Range("B50:B55").ClearContents
    .Range("B50:B" & UBound(VehicleArr) + 49) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(VehicleArr)

End With

FilterRng.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

When I enter "Address1" in cell B4 on Sheet2, I receive the following error:

```
Runtime error '9':

Subscript out of range
```

However, if I save the file with B4 populated and close it, then re open the file, I am able to get the macro to work properly when I edit the cell contents to say either Address1 or Address2.

What is causing the "Subscript out of range" message to appear, and how can I change the code to avoid it?  Do I need to update the code in **Worksheet_Change Code**?

I've also noticed that if I delete the contents of cell B4 on Sheet2 I get the following error:

```
Run-time error'1004':

No cells were found.
```

Are these two errors related?

Comment: You will have issues (although not with this data) if there are more services (or vehicles) than rows of data.  E.g. if your current rows 2 to 6 were deleted, and your current row 7 was the only row, then you would be dimensioning `ServiceArr` as `1 To 2` but trying to store 6 values in it.

Comment: Your `no cells were found` is caused because (if `FilterVal` is `""`) no cells are visible when you hit the `For Each cell In .Range("B2:B" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` statement.  You could get around that by starting the range at B1 and then inserting an `If cell.Row > 1 Then` (with the `End If` just before `Next cell`).  But you would also need to do something then with the Redim of `ServiceArr` to avoid it being dimensioned `1 To 0`.  (Or you could just exit the subroutine if `FilterVal` was `""` - that would probably be easiest.)

Comment: I can't reproduce your error 9 - which line is it occurring on?

Comment: I expect this list to grow over time, but the number of vehicles and services should not exceed 6 each.  The error occurs at `ServiceArr(j) = Service(i)`

Comment: What is the value of `j` and `i` at that point?  Based on your test data, I had `j` reaching as high as 7 (6 at that line), but that was still OK because you had 7 rows of data (and therefore `LastRow` was 7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just wildly guessing but can you try the following:

**Option 1**

In stead of:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(ServiceArr) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(ServiceArr)
```

Write:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(ServiceArr) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(ServiceArr)
```

**Option 2**

In stead of:

```
j = 1 ' init array counter
```

Write:

```
j = 0 ' init array counter
```

---

If nothing works, give information about the line of the error. E.g. once you see the error message, press debug and see on which line is colored in yellow.

Comment: I tried both and received the `ServiceArr(j) = Service(i)` line seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum '`j`' isn't bounded by the number of rows on the sheet - it's bounded by *the number of elements that you can split out of those rows*. There's no way to determine before your code executes what size `ServiceArr` needs to be dimensioned to. That means depending on the data, you'll get intermittent subscript errors in this section:

> ```
> ReDim ServiceArr(1 To LastRow)  '<-- This is only a guess.
> j = 1
> For Each cell In .Range("B2:B" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
>     Service = Split(cell.Value, ",")
>     For i = LBound(Service) To UBound(Service)
>         Service(i) = Trim(Service(i))
>         If Not Dict.exists(Service(i)) Then
>             Dict.Add Service(i), Service(i)
>             ServiceArr(j) = Service(i) '<--Subscript error here if unique elements > LastRow
>             j = j + 1
>         End If
>     Next i
> Next cell
> ```

The solution is ridiculously easy - get rid of `ServiceArr` completely. It will always be exactly the same thing as both `Dict.Keys` and `Dict.Values` because you're basically keeping a *3rd identical copy of the same data* here:

> ```
>             Dict.Add Service(i), Service(i)
>             ServiceArr(j) = Service(i)
> ```

This does almost exactly the same thing as your code, except it gives you a 0 based array instead of a 1 based array:

```
For Each cell In .Range("B2:B" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Service = Split(cell.Value, ",")
    For i = LBound(Service) To UBound(Service)
        Service(i) = Trim(Service(i))
        If Not Dict.exists(Service(i)) Then
            Dict.Add Service(i), Empty
        End If
    Next i
Next cell

ServiceArr = Dict.Keys
'...
'Adjust this to 0 based.
For i = LBound(ServiceArr) To UBound(ServiceArr)
```

See [@YowE3K's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6535336/yowe3k) for why you get the other error.